# Adding <%%> inside a javascript function will be executed by force on page load?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i have the following javascript function:

```
        function redirect() {
        window.setTimeout(function () { <% Response.Redirect("~/Pages/ExecrcisePlan.aspx"); %> }, 2000);
    }
```

I wanted to call this function from inside my asp.net page but it's executing when i enter the page and redirecting me without even calling the function, and event when i commented that line same thing happened, i know i can use other javascript alternative but was curios why it didn't work and if there is anyway to make it work ?

Comment: Server code runs on the server before it is sent to the browser. When you say that in your page it is executing BEFORE being sent to the client.

Comment: "it's executing when i enter the page" are you calling redirect function from page load ?

Comment: yes, i tried calling it from within the page, i am redirect as soon as the page open

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use **<% %>** blocks inside an aspx or cshtml page. The code get evaluated immediately on page creation, because they are **server side** code blocks. You can call it by using an ASP.Net AJAX Timer control instead of using pure javascript.

Another alternative would be using an **javascript redirection** method like location.href, and then use a block <% Response.Write(url) %> to output the URL you want.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is:

```
redirect();

function redirect() {
  var x = setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.replace(<% Url.Content("~/Pages/ExecrcisePlan.aspx"); %>);
  }, 2000);
}
```

http://jsbin.com/aQaLuVA/1/